# VS Code C# XML Documentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm on Visual Studio Code and I'm wondering what the shortcut is for creating documentation in C# for functions, variables, and classes since in VS Studio it's just pressing `/` three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any shortcuts in VS Code. I tried search on Stack but it gave me "how to toggle the function comment on hover".

I looked up on the extensions and saw this
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.docomment

It works similar to Visual Studio where you have to press `/` three times.

Answer (score 5):

### Update Dec 16, 2020

This is now included in the default [**c# extension**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) as of [**v1.23.8**](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.23.8)

You'll have to go to Preferences > Text Editor > Formatting and *enable* **Format on Type**

Or add the following in your `settings.json` file:

```json
{
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
}
```

Then adding three slashes `///` above a member will auto-generate the XML doc comment.

[image: xml doc comment example]